# Numeric for loop in Django templates with Context Variable

Tags: django, templates, for-loop

I want to do a Numeric for Loop in Django templates. After some search, I found a very nice snippet:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/779/

With it I can do

```
Syntax:
{% num_range 5 as some_range %}

{% for i in some_range %}
  {{ i }}: Something I want to repeat\n
{% endfor %}

Produces:
0: Something I want to repeat 
1: Something I want to repeat 
2: Something I want to repeat 
3: Something I want to repeat 
4: Something I want to repeat
```

However, it seems that I can only use a number on the {% num_range %} tag (it is 5 here, for example).

The problem is that I what to use a context variable in the position of '5'. Say I have a context {{times}}, which is an integer variable. How can I do something like that:

```
{% num_range times as some_range %}
```

and then to use 'some_range' in the {% for %} tag?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think it should work. Try replacing this under the `RangeNode` class in the snippet:

```
def render(self, context):
    context[self.context_name] = range(int(self.num))
    return ""
```

With this

```
def render(self, context):
    try:
        num = int(self.num)
    except ValueError:
        num = int(context[self.num])
    context[self.context_name] = range(num)
    return ""
```

Comment: Thank you! But I received a KeyError. According to the traceback, it seems happening at `num = int(context[self.num])`, but I'm not sure.